# Convert specific Excel formula to Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, rounding

I am trying to convert this specific formula from an excel spreadsheet to Javascript

```
ROUND(-E10*(E21-E11)*E13/100,-1)
```

This is what I have in my Javascript now

```
Math.round(-$scope.E10 * ($scope.E21 - $scope.E11 ) * $scope.E13 / 100);
```

This gives me a different value and the problem is the way Excel rounds up the numbers because of the `,-1` at the end of the Excel formula which I don't understand and couldn't find it in any excel manuals.

Can someone help me by explaining what does the `,-1` in the Excel round function actually do?

The values I am using in the calculation process are

E10 = 11000

E11 = 5.2

E13 = 1.40

E21 = 4.8

The values are exactly the same in my Javascript and the Excel sheet. The result in Excel is 60, while my Javascript returns 61. If I change the `,-1` to `,1`  the calculation in Excel matches mine in Javascript, but I need to do the opposite and match my Javascript to the excel.

Comment: Don't have an answer, but the excel docs explicitly state what this does: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/round-HP005209239.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP003056144

Comment: To whit: "If num_digits is less than 0, then number is rounded to the left of the decimal point." e.g. 21.5 when -1 is used is rounded to 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter (-1 in your example) specifies to the ROUND function how many digits to use on the approximation.

- 0 would approximate mathematically to the closest integer.
- A positive number (n) would approximate using the most n significant digits - ie. ROUND(1.23456, 3) = 1,235
- A negative number (-n) would approximate the first significant integer digits, then add "0" as padding to the rest - ie. ROUND(1.23456, -1) = 0, ROUND(12.3456, -1) = 10, ROUND(123456.7, -4) = 123500

In js, the Excel round will look something like this:

```
function excelRound(val, num) {
    var coef = Math.pow(10, num);
    return (Math.round(val * coef))/coef
}

excelRound(-$scope.E10 * ($scope.E21 - $scope.E11 ) * $scope.E13 / 100, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/round-function-HP010342858.aspx can help you answer you're question.

`ROUND(number, num_digits)`

- If num_digits is greater than 0 (zero), then number is rounded to the specified number of decimal places.
- If num_digits is 0, the number is rounded to the nearest integer.
- If num_digits is less than 0, the number is rounded to the left of the decimal point.
- To always round up (away from zero), use the ROUNDUP function.
- To always round down (toward zero), use the ROUNDDOWN function.
- To round a number to a specific multiple (for example, to round to the nearest 0.5), use the MROUND function.